# blank output after running programme in Perl command line

Tags: arrays, perl, function

Please can anyone suggest, I am getting a blank output after running the command `c:\>perl txt.pl employee_cost.txt master_table.txt` in Perl cmd for the following programme:

===================================================

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#opening of employee_txt:

my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get txt file on the command line\n";
my $sum = 0;
open(my $employee_cost, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";

while (my $line = <$employee_cost>) {
   chomp $line;
   # opening of master_table.txt:
   my $file = $ARGV[0] or die "Need to get txt file on the command line\n";
   open(my $master_table, '<', $file) or die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";
   while (my $line = <$master_table>) {
      chomp $line;
      #declaration of variables:
      my $sal;
      my $name;
      my $attendance;
      my @num_employees =scalar (@_);
      my $rating;
      my @calsal =0;
      my $good;
      my $average;
      my @employees = 0;
      my @array =0;
      my @department= scalar (@_);
      #Finding out which employee is worthy and calculating his salary with 20% bonus and the total num of worthy employees:

      sub cal {
         my ($sal) = @_; # could also write: my $sal = shift @_;
         if ($attendance eq $good and $rating eq $good ^ $average) {
            my $calsal = $sal + 0.2 * $sal;
            my $num_employees = @calsal;
            print "salary = $calsal, the total number of worthy employees = $num_employees\n";
            return @calsal;
         }
         else {
            print "employee is not worthy\n";
            return; # return no value
         }

         #sum of all extra bonus which will be paid to worthy employees: 
         sub bonus {
            my $bonus= scalar (@_);
            my $calsal = 0; 
            foreach $calsal (@_) {
               $bonus += $calsal;
               print "total extra bonus paid by companay is $bonus\n";
            };
         }
      }

      #the department with max num of worthy employees:

      sub department_worthyemployees {
         my $department= scalar (@_);
         my $num_employees = scalar (@_);
         foreach $num_employees(@_) {
            @department = sort { $b <=> $a } @num_employees;
            print "the department name for highest number of worthy employees is $department[0] \n";
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

===================================================

Contents of 'employee_cost.txt' file:

---

```
name, department, attendence, rating, sal:

A, HR, bad, bad, 1000

B, Sales, good, good, 3000

C, Admin,bad, average, 1500

D,Admin, bad,average, 2000

E,Contract temp, good, average, 2000

F, production, good, bad, 1500
```

---

Contents of 'master_table.txt':

---

```
department number,department,hike(%),number of employees:

1,HR,10%,30

2,marketing,10%,100

3,sales,5%,50

4,admin,15%,20

5,production,14%,60

6,contract_temporary,15%,60
```

---

Comment: Write complete code without heading...And can I know where did you call the sub routines- cal and bonus

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems here:

1. You never open master_table.txt.  Instead you open employee.txt twice.
2. The subroutines never get called, so they will never print anything.
3. You are confusing arrays (starting with `@`) and scalar variables (starting with `$`).
4. The special variable `@_` contains the subroutine arguments within a subroutine.  It doesn't contain anything outside that context.

I think the problem here is that you have written far too much code before checking that it is working.  What you need to do is write the code for one small step and verify that it works before moving on to the next step.

For example, write code that opens the employee file and prints each line.  Once you see that this works, go to the next step (opening the other file and printing each line in the inner loop, for example).  Learning how to use the [Perl debugger](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) will also help in this process.